# How to correct return vector from function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Can you help me with this problem please? I want return vector from function in class Typ to main function:

In class Typ:

```
vector<Test*> NetworkType::createObject(int r1, int r2, r3) {

        vector<test*> te0;
        if (res1 == 1 && res2 == 1 && res3 == 1) {
        TestV *p1 = new TestV("aaa","bbb",3,"ooo","ccc", "ttt", "testX", "sk2");
        TestV *p3 = new TestV("rrr","ddd",3,"ooo","ccc", "ttt", "testY", "sk2");
        //return p1;

        TestV tesV1(*p1);
        te0.push_back(&tesV1);
        TestV tesV2(*p3);
        te0.push_back(&tesV2);

        return te0;

    } else {
    ...
    }
}
```

main:

```
Typ nk;
vector<Test*> p;
p = nk.createObject(p0,p1,p2);
```

output:

```
for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++){
    cout << "\n" + toString(p[i]);
}
```

toString:

```
 std::string toString(Test* arg) {
 TestV* teV = dynamic_cast<TestV*>(arg);
 TestN* teN = dynamic_cast<TestN*>(arg);

 if (teV)
 {
  return teV->toString();
 }
 else 
 {
      return teN->toString();
 }
 return "";
};
```

Compilation is correct, but after run the program I have obtained this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x76dac41f in VolbaHoneypotu.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: std::__non_rtti_object at memory location 0x002fec9c..

Thank you for reply.

Comment: Did you mean `te0.push_back(&tesV1);`? What you had is not declared there, and if you meant this, it's [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Comment: Wait, what's with that dynamic casting in `toString`? You're recreating virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the vectors nor with the return value of the function. The exception message clearly says what's wrong: your supposed objects are really not objects - because you're putting the address of a block scope object with automatic storage duration ("local variable") to the vector, and that's invalid, so your program invokes undefined behavior.

(This holds only if you meant

```
te0.push_back(&tesV1);
```

instead of

```
te0.push_back(&hpv1);
```

else your code doesn't even compile.)

Comment: I am sorry for mistakes in my code. Cause of these mistakes is rewriting to English language. I changed wrong names to correct names. I need create several objects according evaluation of conditions. These objects I need return to the main function. There I want write these objects to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

(There are several typos in your code, I'm assuming you meant "tesV1" instead of "hpv1" and consistently either "Test" or "test" and so on.)

You are pushing pointers to variables allocated on the stack in your createObject() function:

```
    TestV tesV1(*p1);
    te0.push_back(&hpV1);
    HoneypotV tesV2(*p3);
    te0.push_back(&hpV2);
```

These objects are *copies* of objects allocated on the heap (with "new"), but that does not matter. Once the scope ends (when you return from the function), the objects on the stack disappear. When you dereference the pointers after that, you get into trouble.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but if you push pointers to the heap-allocated objects directly you will not get into this kind of trouble:

```
    te0.push_back( p1 );
    te0.push_back( p2 );
```

Note also that when you allocate an object with "new", it is generally expected that you should also de-allocate it with "delete". The code as you have written it leaks memory -- the memory allocated in createObject() can never be freed.

Comment: I am sorry for mistakes in my code. I changed wrong names to correct names. I need create several objects according evaluation of conditions. This is design pattern Factory.   I need these objects return to the main function. There I want write these objects as vector to the screen.